# Setting unknown property: dektrium\user\models\User::confirmed_at

Tags: yii2

I have problem with dektrium\yii2-user when sign up form submitted going to error **Setting unknown property: dektrium\user\models\User::confirmed_at**

i just setup config

```
'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        ],
```

help me out this error

Comment: update your question and add  the action code where you have this problem ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm gonna guess you didn't run the migrations

```
php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations
```

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md